# Struggling understanding a part in an exercise

Tags: python, computer-science

Link to exercise:

http://books.google.no/books?id=Hi1KVomG148C&lpg=PA231&ots=tyhy6959R7&dq=exercise%205.13%20python%20scientific&hl=no&pg=PA231#v=onepage&q&f=false

Exercise **5.13**, bottom of that page: **231**.

What I actually is struggeling with is in that notation **not** sigma, but that other one. That one who multiplies. There will you find xj! And I can't see where that xj comes from! So when I try to program it, I just... wonder where that xj is suppose to come from...

Thank you so much for all help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you're looking at a typo in that book. x<sub>j</sub> should be x<sub>i</sub>. See [Lagrange Interpolating Polynomial](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LagrangeInterpolatingPolynomial.html) for reference.

**EDIT**: I found the [errata list](http://simula.no/intro-programming/erratalist2nd.pdf) (see Item #5) for the second edition of this book. It is indeed a typo.